# Pydantic Serializing Relationship

Tags: python, pydantic

Is it possible using Pydantic to serialize large shared objects between parent objects?

For example, in this code:

```py
from typing import List, Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Child(BaseModel):
    description: str

class Parent(BaseModel):
    id: int
    large: Optional[Child] = None


external_data = {
    'id': '123',
    'signup_ts': '2019-06-01 12:22',
    'friends': [1, 2, '3'],
}

c1 = Child(description="THIS IS A VERY LONG DESCRIPTION THAT I ONLY WANT TO WRITE ONCE")

p1 = Parent(id=123, large=c1)
p2 = Parent(id=456, large=c1)

class ParentList(BaseModel):
    list: List[Parent]

print(ParentList(list=[p1, p2]).json(indent=4))
```

The output would be

```json
{
    "list": [
        {
            "id": 123,
            "large": {
                "description": "THIS IS A VERY LONG DESCRIPTION THAT I ONLY WANT TO WRITE ONCE"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 456,
            "large": {
                "description": "THIS IS A VERY LONG DESCRIPTION THAT I ONLY WANT TO WRITE ONCE"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Imagine that the large fields are REALLY large, and I only want to represent them once.

I'm imagining an output something like this:

```
{
    "child": {
        "1": {
            "id": "1",
            "description": "THIS IS A VERY LONG DESCRIPTION THAT I ONLY WANT TO WRITE ONCE"
        }
    },
    "parent": {
        "123": {
            "id": "123",
            "large": "1"
        },
        "456": {
            "id": "456",
            "large": "1"
        }
    }
}
```

There is a JS library that does something similar to this called [Normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/tree/master/docs).

Is this built into Pydantic? Would it be hard to implement or is it beyond scope of library?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the output that you would like? I think it might help to understand what you want.

Answer (score 0):

overriding `json()` from pydantic's `BaseModel` might be the solution you are looking for.

https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/#modeljson